# What is params of <sensor> in ros2_control use for?

Tags: parameters, sensor, ros2-control

I'm follow the example 4 in ros2_control_demos, and in [file](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/example_4/description/ros2_control/rrbot_system_with_sensor.ros2_control.xacro), there have following lines:

```
<sensor name="${prefix}tcp_fts_sensor">
    <state_interface name="force.x"/>
    <state_interface name="torque.z"/>
    <param name="frame_id">tool_link</param>
    <param name="fx_range">100</param>
    <param name="tz_range">15</param>
  </sensor>
```

What is the purpose and where is the define or declaration of 3 param above? I see param "frame_id" is used in yaml file, but i can't find any information of the others. I know those are optional param but i can't imagine how it works. Please give me some information of those param. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning ros2. So from what I understood, the frame_id inside the xacro file is just for reference for the sensor data you will receive as a state interface. In yaml file, the sensor data are just used for broadcasting the data, which in turn will used by rviz2 and you will not have problem visualizing data in rviz.
Please refer the rrbor urdf, there you will see the tool_link defined.https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/ros2_control_demo_description/rrbot/urdf/rrbot_description.urdf.xacro
I hope it helps!

Comment: Ahh, thank you, i got it. So the frame_id: in yaml is the parameters of Controller(broacast) and the tool_link in it is the one of the Robot description, not the tool_link in <param> tag of <sensor> tag like the code in the question. 
So None of those three params above were used.

Comment: But one more problem, if i want to use those params, how do i do?

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are just for demonstration purposes and aren't used by either hardware plugin used by the example (`mock_components/GenericSystem` or `ros2_control_demo_example_4/RRBotSystemWithSensorHardware`)

The only parameters which actually get parsed are from the `<hardware>` tag like `example_param_max_sensor_change`, see this [section](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/36aa37235f1f5f27bd40085378e429d14a7e0aa9/example_4/hardware/rrbot_system_with_sensor.cpp#L42-L47).

For sake of completeness, the parameters within the components could be parsed from custom hardware components plugins from [this variable](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/blob/a1b03771eb89425af2dcb06ed57e16de7e3809c4/hardware_interface/include/hardware_interface/hardware_info.hpp#L69).

Comment: Thank you very much, but i still have something unclear.
Did you mean that if i want to use param from <sensor> (ex "fx_range"  just like above ) , i have to implement it in RRBotSystemWithSensorHardware in <hardware> tag ? Or where else for implement it if i want to use <sensor> parameters?
I understand the <param> in <hardware>,<joint>,<gpio>,... where define and use it in all example that i read but stuck of those in <sensor>.

Comment: Have a look into the code of [mock_component](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/blob/b8c5418aff40ae1762c3811a6958ce4e5c1621ba/hardware_interface/src/mock_components/generic_system.cpp#L144), how the parameters for mimicked joints are parsed. On the other hand, the parameters from the hardware tag can be parsed as shown [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/blob/b8c5418aff40ae1762c3811a6958ce4e5c1621ba/hardware_interface/src/mock_components/generic_system.cpp#L99).